# Reloading Observable using Angular2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

**Description:**

I am currently using `Angular2` (`Angular4` now I guess). I am subscribing to a service: `this.policyService.getBaseCommission().subscribe(response => response)` in the `constructor`. This data is able to be updated from a form on the same page.

**Problem:**

I want to be able to refresh that subscription, reload the data and display it in the `html` without having to manually refresh the page. A few answers on SO spoke of solutions in `RC`. I'm in `4.0`. I want to be able to add a record into the db, and refresh the data that is already being subscribed to.

**Question:**

How am I able to refresh the data without having to reload the page? How can I cause my subscribe to fire another request and update `Angular2` accordingly.

**What I have tried so far:**

While this does work, I'm subscribing again and on many refreshes, I'll be creating new subscriptions each time - at least I think that is true...

```
constructor() { this.reloadData(); }

reloadData () : void {
    this.policyService.getBaseCommission().subscribe(response => response)
}

// this gets called from the form on the page and should reload data
createPolicy () : void {
    this.policyService.anotherServiceCall().subscribe(response => {
        this.reloadData();
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't get the refresh thing...you want to reload the data but when? on some event or after some time interval or when? and why? lil more description for the problem plz..

Comment: Updated the question: `createPolicy` gets called on completion of inline form @HimanshuBansal

Comment: By the way, it's only Angular 4 is you've actually updated your package.json accordingly. Otherwise it's still Angular 2.

Comment: Not clear on exactly when or on what event you want to re-load the data, but why not use the appropriate Angular life cycle hook to handle this?

Comment: @Muirik What event reloads data? I want to manually fire the subscribe method again to refresh its data.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood yo want to call `getBaseCommission` at the start and then call it on each form update. You can model your form updates as a stream:

```ts
formUpdates = new Subject<any>();
```

write to this stream when you need to call `anotherServiceCall`

```ts
this.formUpdates.next();
```

and reload commission after that:

```ts
this.formUpdates
  .switchMap(() => {
    return this.policyService.anotherServiceCall();
  })
  .startWith('initial')
  .switchMap((x) => {
    return this.policyService.getBaseCommission(x);
  })
  .subscribe((commission) => {
    this.commission = commission;
  });
```

Note using of `startWith` it is needed to load commission on init before any update of form.

Check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lgOSPnrTBOLuG4O3kRPx?p=preview) for working example.